# Select Only Positive Values and Prepend a Title

Tags: sorting, labeling, functional

I have the following list:

```
{{{Dose -> -15.5527}, {Dose -> 11.6739}}, {{Dose -> -38.1527}, {Dose -> 4.75876}}, {{Dose -> -46.9014}, {Dose -> 3.87109}}}
```

This was generated by the following function:

```
Table[Solve[x, Dose], {x, Thread[functions == 0.05]}]
```

How should I go  about selecting only the positive elements of this list and prepend titles to it? I'd like end up with something like:

```
X-Rays:    11.67 Gy
6.3 Mev:   4.76  Gy
4.3 MeV:   3.87  Gy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TableForm@Transpose@
   {
     {"X-Rays:", "6.3 MeV:", "4.3 MeV:"}
     , ToString[#] <> " Gy" & /@ Select[Dose /. Join @@ lst, Positive]
   }
```

[image]

To get the rounded numbers as you have displayed, replace the `Select` expression with

```
Select[Round[Dose /. Join @@ lst, 0.01], Positive]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Grid[
 Transpose[{
   {"X-Rays:", "6.3 MeV:", "4.3 MeV:", "2.2 MeV:"},
   Cases[Catenate@list, {Rule[_, a_?Positive]} :> Round[a, 0.01]],
   Array["Gy" &, Length@cas]}],
 Frame -> True,
 Spacings -> {2, 1.5},
 Alignment -> {{Left, Right}}]
```

[image]